# python: error reading files into data frame

Tags: python, file, import

I'm trying to import multiple csv files in one folder into one data frame.  This is my code.  It can iterate through the files and print them successfully and it can read one file into a data frame but combining them is printing an error.  I saw many questions similar but the responses are complex, I thought the 'pythonic' way is to be simple because I am new to this.  Thanks in advance for any help.  The error message is always: No such file or directory: 'some file name' which makes no sense because it successfully printed the file name in the print step.

```
import pandas as pd   

# this works
df = pd.read_csv("headlines/2017-1.csv") 
print(df)

path = 'C:/.../... /.../headlines/'  <--- full path I shortened it here
files = os.listdir(path)   
print(files)     <-- prints all file names successfully

for filename in files:
    print(filename)   # <-- successfully prints all file names
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)  # < -- error here
    df2.append(df) # append to data frame
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(filename)` requires full path to `filename` except if the file is in the same directory as the python file.

Comment: Hi, yes, the code uses the full path.  the headlines directory is one level below the folder where my code is.  I am not sure why it can print the file name but not import it.

Comment: could you post a sample output of `filename`?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was on the wrong level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your current working directory is different from your `path`. Please use
`os.chdir(path)` before attempting to read your csv.